# How to get an array for a range per a column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm looking for creating a similar formula:

```
=UNIQUE({A:A;B:B;C:C})
```

So, I need such kind of a range `{A2:A;B2:B;C2:C;...}` (each column separated with the semicolon) for several hundred columns.

Seem, it will be a mess if I will try to type it manually.

Can it be done by Google Sheets features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- drag down the **A9** cell with the blue square as much down as you need
- retrieve your formula from **C2** cell

  [image: 0]
- ### [formula generator spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wEJIphjZS_ELa_2JVB_x0XKKwA7JAuCH1sazwv1MgpU/copy)